# How to recover “last session” files from opera and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opera, macbook-air

After my MacBook crashed and chrome autoupdated, I lost all the tabs in my previous session. In a panic, I made a mistake and closed the new session after opening a history tab. This meant the last session file was Most likely overwritten. 
Further compounding the issue was that later on my MacBook crashed multiple times, which also obliterated my opera session as it crashed in the midst of opening the previous opera session.

I did download photorec, and I’ve used it to recover some files so I *think* I do know what to do.  However, I’ve run into the issue that I don’t have enough memory space to store all the files I’ve deleted.

In the interest of saving space and time, what is the file format I should be looking for in order to find the last session files of opera and chrome? I’d say txt but opening either one in notepad gave me gibberish.

Also, what activities will raise the chances the files will be overwritten besides installing and running new files?

Finally, what partition should I ask photorec to store recovered files in so it’s unlikely to overwrite the files I’m looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who find this question via search...

You can use [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) for this (for Opera, install the "[Install Chrome Extensions](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/install-chrome-extensions/)" extension first). I don't remember if it can do anything about sessions before it's been installed though.